# VM: Programatically keep a VM "awake"?

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine

I have an Azure VM that I use to connect to a database as a workhorse. If I am remotely connected, e.g., through Bastion (or SSH/RDP), my service will connect and run no problem. If I close my connection, my service will connect and run no problem for some limited time limit. After several hours, the connection to the database will fail.

If I remote back into the VM, I notice its exactly where I left it, all windows still open, etc. If I run a connection to my database, it succeeds. Again, if I leave it alone for a while, the connection to my database fails.

I have tried running powershell commands akin to the belowto keep the machine "alive". What can I do to keep it talking to the internet? The problem seems to be that it is not connecting to the internet after some lengthy timeframe of not being logged into.

```
# try to keep awake
$wsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
while (1) {
  $wsh.SendKeys('+{F15}')
  Start-Sleep -seconds 59
}
```

Comment: Does your machine go to standby? Maybe you can just adjust the energy saving options.

Comment: Great idea! I looked at the sleep states in `powercfg /a`  (all disabled) as well as in control panel but did not see anything that jumped out at me.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the **VM Alive** we can change the settings from **Power & sleep** > **Never**

[image]

For additional settings you can select as below and keep VM awake without falling into sleep.

[image]

For more information please refer this [***GitHub***](https://gist.github.com/jamesfreeman959/231b068c3d1ed6557675f21c0e346a9c) link .